# Remove part of a String in a column (R)

Tags: r

I have dataframe `dataf` with column `PlayerValue`

```
         PlayerName           playerValue
1     Michy Batshuayi        40,00 Mill. €  
2     Tiemoué Bakayoko       35,00 Mill. €  
3     Kurt Zouma             20,00 Mill. €  
4     Kenedy                 10,00 Mill. €  
5     Tammy Abraham          10,00 Mill. €  
6     Abdul Rahman Baba      8,00 Mill. €  
7     Mario Pasalic          8,00 Mill. €  
8     Lewis Baker            5,50 Mill. €  
9     Ola Aina               4,00 Mill. €  
10    Tomas Kalas            4,00 Mill. €
```

I would like to make it get just the number (and if possible replace the comma with a decimal point) in the column like this

```
         PlayerName           playerValue
1     Michy Batshuayi           40,00 # 40.00, if possible
2     Tiemoué Bakayoko          35,00  
3     Kurt Zouma                20,00  
4     Kenedy                    10,00  
5     Tammy Abraham             10,00   
6     Abdul Rahman Baba         8,00   
7     Mario Pasalic             8,00  
8     Lewis Baker               5,50  
9     Ola Aina                  4,00   
10    Tomas Kalas               4,00
```

Comment: If the column is always in `"##,## Mill. €"` format you can simply replace the non-numeric parts with blank character `""`. As in
`library(stringr);
x <- str_replace(x, " Mill. €", "");
x <- str_replace(x, ",", "")
`
But to cover more complicated cases you should first replace the comma with `""` and then use regular expressions (also supported by `stringr` functions) to detect only numeric parts

Answer (score 1):

Use `gsub` to replace anything after the space and also replace `,` to `.`, like this:

```
data$playerValue <- gsub(",", ".", gsub("[[:space:]].*", "", data$playerValue))
```

It will give you this output:

```
#         PlayerName           playerValue
#1     Michy Batshuayi               40.00
#2     Tiemoué Bakayoko              35.00  
#3     Kurt Zouma                    20.00  
#4     Kenedy                        10.00  
#5     Tammy Abraham                 10.00   
#6     Abdul Rahman Baba              8.00   
#7     Mario Pasalic                  8.00  
#8     Lewis Baker                    5.50  
#9     Ola Aina                       4.00   
#10    Tomas Kalas                    4.00
```

This, if you want to convert it to a number, you can do it as follows:

```
data$playerValue <- as.numeric(data$playerValue)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
playerValue <- "40,00 Mill. € "
as.numeric(gsub("^(\\d+?)\\,(\\d+?)\\s.*", "\\1.\\2", playerValue, perl = TRUE))
# returns
40
```

---

Short expl. of the `regex`:

- `^` tells it is the start of the string
- `\\d+\\,\\d+` means there a two sequences of numbers separated by a comma. We extract the two sequences using parentheses
- `\\s.*` means after the second sequence comes a white space and after the space comes anything (nothing is also anything)
- `\\1`,`\\2` are the grouping we want to extract and we separate them by a dot in order to convert them to `numeric`